# Yii display and validation of fields not present in table

Tags: php, templates, yii

I am a newbie in  Yii. I have created a page where user can change their password.

So in my changePassword view I have :

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'oldpwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'oldpwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'oldpwd'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'pwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pwd'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pwd_repeat'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'pwd_repeat'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pwd_repeat'); ?>
</div>
```

Now obviously I am getting an error as only the field 'pwd' is in the table and thereby in the model. I am new to MVC frameworks and can use some help here. Thanks

Comment: Could you show full error/exception description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare them in your model as property of model First..

```
public $old_pwd;
public $pwd;
public $pwd_repeat;
```

As you are asking model Labels of these attributes..define them in your attributeLabels function in model..

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'old_pwd'=>'Old Passw....',
                     '.....same way for all those who are not already there..'
    );
}
```

Declare them safe in rules if required...

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your model

```
public $old_pwd;  
public $pwd_repeat;
```

we instruct Yii to use this field as virtual field instead of searching in database field

Comment: Sorry..I cant because voting requires 15 rep minimum :(